# Designing a rest url - filter with multiple params over entities (not last entity)

Tags: api, rest, web

Let's say I have the following entities in my libraries app - Library Room, shelf, Book.
Where Room has N shelves, and shelves have N Books.

Now the following url brings me a list of books whose
library is 3, room no. is 5 and shelf no. is 43.

```
.../library/3/room/5/shelf/43/books
```

Assuming shelf 43 is unique per room only
(There is shelf 43 also in other rooms)
and Rooms are not unique (There's a few room no. 5 ) in the library.
Here is my questions:

I want to filter with more fields on the entities, here is what i want to do 
(representation not in rest):

```
.../library/id=3&type=3/room/decade=21&topic=horror/shelf/location=east&/books
```

This is not rest.
How do I represent it in rest?
Notes:
I don't want to do this way

```
  .../books&param1=X&param2=X&param3=X&param4=X
```

because not all params are related to books.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things that you need to look into while designing your apis.

1) are `type`, `decade`, `topic` etc required fields? if so, I will probably make them a part of the path itself, such as:

```
../libraries/{libraryId}/type/{typeId}/rooms/{roomId}/decades/{decadeId}/topics/{topicName}/shelves/{shelfId}/locations/{shelfLocation}/books
```

Here I am assuming that each library can have rooms which have unique room ids per library, each room can have shelves which has unique ids/locations per room (and so on and so forth). Yes, the url is pretty long, but that's kind of expected

2) if these fields are not required, you could use a different approach which is a bit less verbose but a bit more confusing for client developers who have never used such approach here. Here's a straight up example `Restful Java with JAX-RS by Bill Burke`

```
 @Path("{first}-{last}")
 @GET
 @Produces("application/xml")
 public StreamingOutput getCustomer(@PathParam("first") String firstName,
 @PathParam("last") String lastName) {

 ...

 }

Here, we have the URI path parameters {first} and {last}. If our HTTP request is
GET /customers/bill-burke, bill will be injected into the firstName parameter and
burke will be injected into the lastName parameter.
```

If we follow this somewhat academic approach (I have not seen this implemented on many platforms. Most platforms normally go with approach # 1, a more verbose but clear approach), your URL would look somewhat like this:

```
../libraries/{libraryId}-{typeId}/rooms/{roomId}-{decadeId}-{topicName}/shelves/{shelfId}-{shelfLocation}/books
```

This way, if the client developer doesn't pass in the non-required fields, you can handle it at the business logic level and assign these variables a default value, for example:

```
../libraries/3-/rooms/2-1-horror/shelves/1-/books
```

With this url, libraryId = 3, typeId = null (thus can be defaulted to it's default value) and so on and so forth. Remember that if libraryId is required field, then you might want to actually make it a part of the pathparam itself

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, great resource. looking into it. Question : you referred to solution #2 as an academic approach. Why? (I want to design standard rest api as I will have many external clients).

Comment: I refer to it as more of an academic approach because I haven't seen it being used much on platform, for instance, google apis, linkedin apis, facebook apis, twitter apis etc. I just keep this knowledge in the back of my mind to remind myself of other approaches as and when needed. Thus academic :)